# SwiftUI: Searchable freezing UI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
enum ViewRouter:Hashable, Codable {
    case pageOne
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var navStackPath = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack(path: $navStackPath) {
            ZStack {
                Button {
                    navStackPath.append(ViewRouter.pageOne)
                } label: {
                    Text("SHOW DETAILS")
                }

            }
            .navigationDestination(for: ViewRouter.self) { d in
                switch d {
                case .pageOne:
                    DetailsView()
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}



struct DetailsView: View {
    
    @State var searchString = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Text("DETAILS")
            
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchString)
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

`DETAILS` button freezes when I go back if search is in focus.
Steps:

1. tap on`SHOW DETAILS`
2. details view shows
3. tap inside search field so keyboard shows up
4. tap back to go back to ContentView
5. Try to tap `SHOW DETAILS` button. **UI is frozen**. Button does not work anymore

Anyone knows why?

Xcode version:
`Version 15.0 beta (15A5160n)`
Also happens with:
`Version 15.0 beta 2 (15A5161b)`

simulator or device do the same. But for example, iPad simulator:

`Version 15.0 (1004)`
`SimulatorKit 633`
`CoreSimulator 905.2`

Only thing I see in logs is this:

`UINavigationBar has changed horizontal size class without updating search bar to new placement. Fixing, but delegate searchBarPlacement callbacks have been skipped. navigationBar = <SwiftUI.UIKitNavigationBar: 0x10ad0c110; baseClass = UINavigationBar; frame = (1366 24; 1366 50); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000c717d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000269d20>> delegate=0x111010000`

Does somebody know how I can prevent the UI from freezing if I press back while search is in focus? How can I fix this?

Comment: I've been able to reproduce this with your code, and just realised I have the exact same issue with an app I'm currently working on where navigation links are broken if the search field is focused when going back. It's probably worth raising it with [Feedback Assistant](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) as it might be a framework bug.

Comment: I haven't had the best luck with searchable in SwiftUI since it came out. Always felt half baked. Hopefully it gets addressed. If I manually dismiss the search focus and tap back then the UI does not freeze, but that does not really solve the problem... Thanks for your feedback.